# How to get TypeScript to infer the correct type when value type can be any number of interfaces?

Tags: typescript, types

Perhaps the title is not clear, this is tough to summarize.

I have two interfaces, such as:

```
interface KeyA {
    a: ValueA;
}

interface KeyB {
    b: ValueB;
}
```

and a type which indicates a given value can be of `KeyA`, `KeyB` , or an empty object:

```
type KeyExpr = KeyA | KeyB | Record<string, never>;
```

Assuming I am given an instance of `KeyExpr` type, I would to access one of it's properties (either `a` or `b` in this example) and have the resulting type be ValueA or ValueB accordingly:

```
function func(keyExpr: KeyExpr) {
    const value = keyExpr['a']; 

    // how to make the type of "value" by ValueA here?
}
```

I am able to obtain the possible keys for `KeyExpr` like so:

```
export type KnownKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K;
} extends infer R
    ? R extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U }
        ? U
        : never
    : never;

const keys = KnownKeys<KeyExpr>;
```

...now the type of `keys` is `"a" | "b"`, but still accessing a property on something that is of `KeyExpr` type yields the type `never` (meaning even though I used a type `"a" | "b"` to access it, it still resolved to that more generic Record type).

Any ideas how to improve this or just can't be done?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with `KnownKeys<T>`, but does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9PK8w) work for you? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  In either case, could you [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE (e.g., either define `ValueA` and `ValueB` or replace them with ambient types).

Comment: That's a neat trick, using the in operator. It's an improvement over what I got... if you write an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a value whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types), you can use [the `in` operator to *narrow* the apparent type of that value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing).  The type checker will automatically filter the union to just those members known to have or not known to have the key you're checking.

In the case of a value of type `KeyExpr`, it looks like this:

```
function func(keyExpr: KeyExpr) {
  if ("a" in keyExpr) {
    // keyExpr narrowed to KeyA
    const value = keyExpr.a // ValueA
  } else if ("b" in keyExpr) {
    // keyExpr narrowed to KeyB
    const value = keyExpr.b // Value B
  } else {
    // keyExpr narrowed to Record<string, never>
    keyExpr // Record<string, never>
  }
```

That works how you'd like it.

---

Note that it is technically not type safe for the type checker to do this, since object types in TypeScript are *open* and values may have properties not known to the compiler.  That is, TypeScript types are not "exact types", as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  So something like this is possible:

```
declare const valueB: ValueB; 
const keyB = { a: "oops", b: valueB };
func(keyB); // no error
```

Here you've created a value named `keyB` which is assignable to `KeyB` but has an excess `a` property.  If you explicitly annotated this like `const keyB: KeyB = {a: "oops", b: valueB }`, you'd get an [excess property warning](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) because the compiler would worry that you're throwing away the `a` property. But without that annotation it's fine.

And then `func(keyB)` compiles with no error because `keyB` is a `KeyB` which is a `KeyExpr`.  And then, unfortunately, the implementation of `func()` goes down the wrong path because the compiler assumes that `("a" in keyExpr)` means that `keyExpr` is a `KeyA`.  If that implementation did any `KeyA`-specific things, you'd likely get a runtime error.

In practice this sort of thing is rare, so you might not need to worry about it.

---

But if you *are* worried about it, then you should really try to make your `KeyExpr` type more robust.  For example, you could make it a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  For example:

```
interface KeyA {
  type: "A",
  a: ValueA;
}

interface KeyB {
  type: "B"
  b: ValueB;
}

type KeyExpr = KeyA | KeyB | Partial<Record<string, never>>;


function func(keyExpr: KeyExpr) {
  if (keyExpr.type === "A") {
    const value = keyExpr.a // ValueA
  } else if (keyExpr.type === "B") {
    const value = keyExpr.b // Value B
  } else {
    keyExpr // Partial<Record<string, never>>
  }
}
```

Now there is a strongly-typed `type` property which will either be `"A"`, `"B"`, or `undefined`, and can be used to unequivocally identify which member of the union a value is:

```
declare const valueB: ValueB;
const keyB = { type: "B" as const, a: "oops", b: valueB };
func(keyB); // okay now
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJIAuAnjMgGqYCuEAgkgLx5IgBcSAjEgL5ESFKkloYGAIVbsARtz6DCQpAEtgpCACcAZgmQBpCOWYFiJDt3ENGAbhVKV6zbv1Ij5aWYtJ5Y+hCS9uaOyuYihsYAogAeMFoyHswAPu7G0qkAShDwAPZaACYAPFCkWuoA5gA0SMAQAG7aAHzBRCo6dMDwpKq5wEgdXQAUANbRcVrcHrHxAJR4KiSqOkhDAEQga2r9Y+QzWvPePkh5wKVI9QEyu-sAdCBIAPSP-hJMiwJIEBhQyMura1kW3USBuE0OHxIp3Olze13G8VusieL2syEkH34Xx+yCOPjB8RRSGyeUKJTKlRqdUaWiamLaIQZUL6MICkisbJkuF8CgEwWZZ1IoPSXMsSDWuVyMCgaxqflhUj57U68FG6VmtiJkulTNq4GgcEQSAAIqooPBymAAKoLczCSg0ALMNjcri8AQfCKvRUunnu0I+ZzaPRGpK245kB3cNaMWWQsVouz0sKBjTBtweLzxiLRyRreN+NFBZOeh1pPYTRLGFLljJIAAKIC0PUwRRJ+WKpXKwGqtQazRaDI+g26vX6I7VFfiUwRB3Dx3+k7uXpYq-FsYhduO0KFCuQbAJWnuRMT8ax31+ahWS4mtxXa7Wec3EYFrLhB9nSJPVwxW5I55xecI0PIlG2bVRW3bMku0pPsaSaOk-w9LcAwsHcLjZDk3mkX0-EUfk0JZIVdhw9gc3FPMOCgE4iJqN0JSlGU5W4PdpH4AiSAnEiNV1JR+CAA)